# MouseMotionListener not Firing correctly in Java

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

can anyone tell me why the mouseMotionListener is not firing the mouseDragged event(I have googled for hours and even copy-and-pasted code from the net!) Below is the code for the class - I create an object of the class and add it to a JPanel called canvas.

PS the mousePressed() is the only method that gets fired, mouseDragged() and mouseReleased(), they do not.

```
class MouseActions extends MouseInputAdapter 
{
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            super.mousePressed(e);//245 220
            java.awt.Point Pos = e.getPoint();
            System.out.println("at Mouse Pressed, Again");
            if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
            {
                if(ArrayOfShapes == null)
                    return;

                for(int i = 0; i < ArrayOfShapes.length; i++)
                {
                    if(hasEntered(ArrayOfShapes[i], Pos))
                    {
                        removeAtIndex(i);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
        {
           System.out.println("at Mouse Dragged");
            int MovableIndex = -1;
            java.awt.Point Pos = e.getPoint();

            if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
            {
                bDragged = true;

                while(bDragged)
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < ArrayOfShapes.length; i++)
                    {
                        if(hasEntered(ArrayOfShapes[i], Pos))
                        {
                            MovableIndex = i;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    ArrayOfShapes[MovableIndex].setX(e.getX());
                    ArrayOfShapes[MovableIndex].setY(e.getY());
                    thisCurrentWindow.repaint();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            System.out.println("at Mouse Release");
            bDragged = false;
        }

    }
```

/// Now the code to add the listeners

```
MouseActions MA = new MouseActions();
canvas.addMouseListener(MA);
canvas.addMouseMotionListener(MA);
```

Again Thanks alot~

M

PS.... For all who are doubting my mad inheritance skills

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;


public class CustomJPanel extends JPanel
{
    class MouseActions extends MouseInputAdapter
    {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            super.mousePressed(e);
            System.out.println("Pressed");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            super.mouseDragged(e);
            System.out.println("Dragged");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            super.mouseReleased(e);
            System.out.println("Released");
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    private CustomJPanel()
    {
        MouseActions ma = new MouseActions();
        addMouseListener(ma);
        addMouseMotionListener(ma);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO code application logic here
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        CustomJPanel cP = new CustomJPanel();

        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        cP.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.add(cP);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Again when I assign this to canvas it never fires the release or the dragged

M

Comment: Better if you could post a small compilable and *runnable* program that demonstrates your problem, an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org).

Comment: Also your `while (dragged)` looks to possibly stomp on the Swing event thread. I strongly advise you to get rid of code like that.

Comment: not sure now if is that correct, why did you put together two separated MouseListeners 1) MouseListener, 2) MouseMotionListener, edit your question with a SSCCE,

Comment: @Markus: How'd you get it to work? By getting rid of the `while (dragged)` loop?

Comment: O Crap - It doesnt work! I changed the while to if, but for some reason - running this in my Custom JPANEL it doesnot Fire the release or Drag BUT IF I CREATE a new CLASS FROM JPANEL and then add simple events like output then it works.... IF I copy it again to canvas's class(ShapePanel) then it doesnt work

Comment: @HFoE - as asked here in is the runnable code - i want this in my other class (see amended question)

Comment: the whole point of an SSCCE in a question is to demonstrate reproducibly what is _not_ working :-) So try again: strip down your real code into the smallest possible unit that _does not_ work and show that instead of the oversimplified runnable that does ..

Answer (score 1):

The loop while(bDragged) looks like an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

As far I can see you need to implement the mouse listener. Referring to: http://profs.etsmtl.ca/mmcguffin/learn/java/04-mouseInput/

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer since all it is is a link and doesn't explain why the OP's code doesn't work.

Comment: My bad... but the user above me did post it too. :)
As long as your question gets answered.

But the explaination is that IF you register an listener, it needs to implement the listener too.

Answer (score 0):

Scary enough - i worked just the way it was coded to.... Except later in the code i removed the canvas and recreated it - but forgetting to reassign the MIA.

Thanks for all your help,

M

Answer (score -2):

I would do this:

```
class MouseActions implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener
{
..
..
}

canvas.addMouseListener(new MouseActions ());
canvas.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseActions() );
```

and that would probably work.

Comment: Why would this help at all since MouseInputAdapter already implements both interfaces (and more)?

Comment: I dont know why it helps, but it works at all. maybe why this works is another question to ask. So go this way: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: What I'm saying is that your answer is not helpful to the original poster and has 0% chance of solving his problem.